# Select multiple values from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have the following dataframe:

```
PIC   Label   EncodedPixels
pic1  fish    True
pic1  flower  True
pic1  gravel  False
pic1  sugar   False
pic2  fish    True
pic2  flower  True
```

What i want to do is this:

for every EQUAL value in PIC, count the labels that coexist (being the true value).
 For instance, sow the number of times that fish and flower coexist for every pic.

I can count each individual value in the following way:

```
df.loc[ (df['Pixels'] == True ) & (df['Label'] == 'Sugar') ])
```

The expected output is the number of combinations for each pic. For instance, in pic1 fish and flower are both true in EncodedPixels, so the output would be 2
How can i do the rest?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: This is a bit confusing because it's unclear what is a constraint, and what is something you calculated on a way to a solution. If the problem is simply to count how many PICs have fish and flower this is simple. I'm not sure I see why EncodedPixels comes into play. Is it ever False when the label is fish/flower or True when it's not? Is PIC/Label a unique key for the DataFrame?

Comment: The expected output is the number of combinations for each pic. For instance, in pic1 fish and flower are both true in EncodedPixels, so the output would be 2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're asking for:

```
df

>>> PIC Label   EncodedPixels
    0   pic1    fish    True
    1   pic1    flower  True
    2   pic1    gravel  False
    3   pic1    sugar   False
    4   pic2    fish    True
    5   pic2    flower  True


helper_df = df.groupby(['PIC', 'Label']).apply(lambda grp: grp['EncodedPixels'].sum()).unstack()
helper_df


>>> Label   fish    flower  gravel  sugar
    PIC             
    pic1    1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
    pic2    1.0 1.0 NaN NaN
```

I would suggest just using the table above if you have more labels, since this next step is `n^2`. However, If you just want a pic-level count of each label, then this df satisfies that:

```
output_df = pd.DataFrame(index = df['Label'].unique(), columns = df['Label'].unique())

for ind_x in output_df.columns:
    for ind_y in output_df.columns:
        output_df.loc[ind_x, ind_y] = helper_df[helper_df[ind_x] & helper_df[ind_y]].sum()[ind_x]

output_df

    >>> fish    flower  gravel  sugar
        fish    2   2   0   0
        flower  2   2   0   0
        gravel  0   0   0   0
        sugar   0   0   0   0
```

Also, good luck on Kaggle ;P